# How to read Protobuf files with Dask?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, dask, dask-distributed, rapids

Has anyone tried reading Protobuf files over Dask? Each Protobuf file I have, has multiple records, and each record is prefixed with the length of the record (4 bytes) as shown in the snippet.

This is what the current code to read/parse these files looks like:

```
import mystream.MyPacket_pb2 as pb
import struct
​
def read_uint32(data): # little endian
    return struct.unpack('<L', data)[0]
​
def parse(filepath):
    packets = []
    prefix = 4
    pos, data = 0, open(filepath, 'rb').read()
    count = 0
    while pos < len(data):
        next_pos = read_uint32(data[pos:pos+4])
        packet = pb.MyPacket()
        packet.ParseFromString(data[prefix+pos:prefix+pos+next_pos])
        pos += prefix + next_pos
        packets.append(packet)
    return packets
​
# Some more processing to follow after
```

The code snippet standalone runs fine, but fails over Dask when using a simple `distributed.Client.submit()/map()` with the error: `Exception: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor' object`.

I also left a comment on the only GitHub discussion I could find on Protobuf & Dask [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1434#issuecomment-1105166160). This is a pretty interesting discussion, but it's been 6 years already.

I'd love to hear if any one has ideas on how we can get something like this to work, if at all possible.

**EDIT: Posting the entire example here.**

```
import json
import struct
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
import mapstream.MapstreamPacket_pb2 as pb

def read_uint32(data): # little endian
    return struct.unpack('<L', data)[0]

def parse_mapstream(path):
    prefix = 4
    pos, data = 0, open(path, 'rb').read()
    count = 0
    # Just parse the first 3 packets for testing
    while pos < len(data) and count < 3:
        next_pos = read_uint32(data[pos:pos+4])
        packet = pb.MapstreamPacket()
        packet.ParseFromString(data[prefix+pos:prefix+pos+next_pos])
        pos += prefix + next_pos
        count += 1
        yield packet

# the packet message is one of these types
factories = {
    pb.PacketType.TRAJECTORY: pb.TrajectoryPacket,
}

# given a packet wrapper, decode the wrapped packet type
def dispatch(packet):
    factory = factories[packet.type]()
    factory.ParseFromString(packet.message)
    return factory

def extract_packets():
    path = "uncompressed-ms.protobuf"
    packets1 = parse_mapstream(path)
    wanted = set([pb.PacketType.TRAJECTORY])
    packets2 = (dispatch(packet) for packet in packets1 if packet.type in wanted)
    packets3 = (MessageToJson(packet) for packet in packets2)
    list_packets3 = list(packets3)
    # Return only the first packet as JSON
    return json.dumps(json.loads(list_packets3[0]), indent=2)


# Without Dask
print(extract_packets())

# With Dask
import distributed
client = distributed.Client("dask-scheduler-ip")
client.get_versions(check=True)
res = client.submit(extract_packets)
print(client.gather(res))
```

Output w/o Dask:

```
{
  "geoPose": {
    "longitude": 11.675636545410766,
    "latitude": 48.036162288714884,
    "altitude": 567.4531918477081,
    "rigToENU": {
      "x": -0.009063592,
      "y": -0.00394439,
      "z": -0.9173354,
      "w": 0.39799264
    },
    "locationCovariance": [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0
    ],
    "rotationCovariance": [
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0,
      0.0
    ]
  }
}
```

Error w/ Dask:

```
distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to serialize <function extract_packets at 0x7f10c436ee50>. Exception: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor' object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py:4480, in dumps_function(func)
   4479     with _cache_lock:
-> 4480         result = cache_dumps[func]
   4481 except KeyError:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/utils.py:1358, in LRU.__getitem__(self, key)
   1357 def __getitem__(self, key):
-> 1358     value = super().__getitem__(key)
   1359     self.data.move_to_end(key)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/collections/__init__.py:1010, in UserDict.__getitem__(self, key)
   1009     return self.__class__.__missing__(self, key)
-> 1010 raise KeyError(key)

KeyError: <function extract_packets at 0x7f10c436ee50>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py:44, in dumps(x, buffer_callback, protocol)
     43         buffers.clear()
---> 44         result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
     45 elif not _always_use_pickle_for(x) and b"__main__" in result:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:73, in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     70 cp = CloudPickler(
     71     file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72 )
---> 73 cp.dump(obj)
     74 return file.getvalue()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:602, in CloudPickler.dump(self, obj)
    601 try:
--> 602     return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    603 except RuntimeError as e:

TypeError: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor' object

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 8>()
      5 client.get_versions(check=True)
      6 client
----> 8 res = client.submit(extract_packets)
      9 print(client.gather(res))

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py:1758, in Client.submit(self, func, key, workers, resources, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, allow_other_workers, actor, actors, pure, *args, **kwargs)
   1755 else:
   1756     dsk = {skey: (func,) + tuple(args)}
-> 1758 futures = self._graph_to_futures(
   1759     dsk,
   1760     [skey],
   1761     workers=workers,
   1762     allow_other_workers=allow_other_workers,
   1763     priority={skey: 0},
   1764     user_priority=priority,
   1765     resources=resources,
   1766     retries=retries,
   1767     fifo_timeout=fifo_timeout,
   1768     actors=actor,
   1769 )
   1771 logger.debug("Submit %s(...), %s", funcname(func), key)
   1773 return futures[skey]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/client.py:2898, in Client._graph_to_futures(self, dsk, keys, workers, allow_other_workers, priority, user_priority, resources, retries, fifo_timeout, actors)
   2896 # Pack the high level graph before sending it to the scheduler
   2897 keyset = set(keys)
-> 2898 dsk = dsk.__dask_distributed_pack__(self, keyset, annotations)
   2900 # Create futures before sending graph (helps avoid contention)
   2901 futures = {key: Future(key, self, inform=False) for key in keyset}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/highlevelgraph.py:1055, in HighLevelGraph.__dask_distributed_pack__(self, client, client_keys, annotations)
   1049 layers = []
   1050 for layer in (self.layers[name] for name in self._toposort_layers()):
   1051     layers.append(
   1052         {
   1053             "__module__": layer.__module__,
   1054             "__name__": type(layer).__name__,
-> 1055             "state": layer.__dask_distributed_pack__(
   1056                 self.get_all_external_keys(),
   1057                 self.key_dependencies,
   1058                 client,
   1059                 client_keys,
   1060             ),
   1061             "annotations": layer.__dask_distributed_annotations_pack__(
   1062                 annotations
   1063             ),
   1064         }
   1065     )
   1066 return {"layers": layers}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/highlevelgraph.py:425, in Layer.__dask_distributed_pack__(self, all_hlg_keys, known_key_dependencies, client, client_keys)
    420 merged_hlg_keys = all_hlg_keys | dsk.keys()
    421 dsk = {
    422     stringify(k): stringify(v, exclusive=merged_hlg_keys)
    423     for k, v in dsk.items()
    424 }
--> 425 dsk = toolz.valmap(dumps_task, dsk)
    426 return {"dsk": dsk, "dependencies": dependencies}

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/toolz/dicttoolz.py:83, in valmap(func, d, factory)
     72 """ Apply function to values of dictionary
     73 
     74 >>> bills = {"Alice": [20, 15, 30], "Bob": [10, 35]}
   (...)
     80     itemmap
     81 """
     82 rv = factory()
---> 83 rv.update(zip(d.keys(), map(func, d.values())))
     84 return rv

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py:4518, in dumps_task(task)
   4516         return d
   4517     elif not any(map(_maybe_complex, task[1:])):
-> 4518         return {"function": dumps_function(task[0]), "args": warn_dumps(task[1:])}
   4519 return to_serialize(task)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/worker.py:4482, in dumps_function(func)
   4480         result = cache_dumps[func]
   4481 except KeyError:
-> 4482     result = pickle.dumps(func, protocol=4)
   4483     if len(result) < 100000:
   4484         with _cache_lock:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py:51, in dumps(x, buffer_callback, protocol)
     49 try:
     50     buffers.clear()
---> 51     result = cloudpickle.dumps(x, **dump_kwargs)
     52 except Exception as e:
     53     logger.info("Failed to serialize %s. Exception: %s", x, e)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:73, in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     69 with io.BytesIO() as file:
     70     cp = CloudPickler(
     71         file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72     )
---> 73     cp.dump(obj)
     74     return file.getvalue()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/rapids-22.04/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py:602, in CloudPickler.dump(self, obj)
    600 def dump(self, obj):
    601     try:
--> 602         return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    603     except RuntimeError as e:
    604         if "recursion" in e.args[0]:

TypeError: cannot pickle 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageDescriptor' object
```

Comment: Do you want to parallelise over files or messages? Are you always reading locally? I assume using distributed (processes) is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Martin! I want to parallelize over files so that each Dask worker processes one or more files (each worker will process files sequentially) independent of other workers. 

End goal is to use this within streamz (since you have context) where a stream reads a batch of messages from Kafka which has S3 paths to these files.

Comment: I haven't managed to recreate the situation. Can you create a complete example with the generated .py file and/or example binary string to parse? As far as I can tell, the protobuf class instances MyPacket should be pickleable.

Comment: @mdurant, sorry for the extremely long delay! I have edited the post with the complete example and the error. I'm thinking there is something in the Protobuf class that is causing the pickling error. How can we dig in deeper?